# How to position/expand axis X starting point so that it aligns with axis Y lowest point

Tags: vb.net, charts, alignment, axis

When new chart is created, default is that the first and last point are not aligned with Y axis but they are somewhere in the middle of the X axis.

[image]

I can not figure out how to put "2010" all the way to the left and "TTM" all the way to the right. Almost half the chartarea space is lost like this.

In Excel it is "position X axis between tick marks" option, but I don't know how to do that in vb.net.

Thanks

Comment: Which component create your chart ?

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, chart is created from 4 rows (DGV).

Comment: I mean, since I'm not satisfied by the Excel Charts, nor the Google ones, and would like to have any of my application charts capabilities, I ended up creating a whole set of classes an user controls to render charts : axis, background, lines, headers, pies, 2D, 3D, etc. In vbNet.. and can output a chart like yours. Excel can aswell, and google too in SVG. Maybe others applications.. You just said you knew how to do it in Excel, so you're not talking about Excel. "_But in vbNet_" -> either it's ASP on some chart API, either user generated chart on bitmap like mine. How is you chart created ?

Comment: I used Excel as reference in case I am not clear enough what I wanted. I thought that spreading X axis points between 2 Y axis would be without gaps as default, but I was wrong. Also, I can not find anything in VBStudio properties that would change that.

Comment: To answer your question CSV is imported from MorningStar website (KeyRatios for the last 5 years) into datagridview. Axis X points are years, 1 series contains 1 set of values from DGV row and so on. Then I've added points to each series from DGV using For loop. I can edit original post, if you want, to provide the code used to crate that chart, but there is nothing there that would help fix my problem, because I don't even know what to use (scale chartarea or...) to achieve that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mmmh I see : you're using :

- either a `System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart`
- or a `System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart`

That's what I asked by *"Which component create your chart ?"*

One of the reasons I ended creating my own way of rendering charts from A to Z is the issue like yours.

Anyway, your problem is the *"add axis then modify min/max syndrome"*. I don't use your component a lot, so I don't really have the fix to the issue. What I know is :

- When you create a Charting.Chart component (or add one to your project)
- then you add X and Y axis

^^ those ones are somewhat locked :( - Didn't checked how to modify them after...
What I've done as a workaround long ago is :

- create programatically the X and Y axes **without adding them to the ChartArea**.
- define X min and max values
- then when I'm done, set the chartArea X and Y axis accordingly

  ```
  ' Imports System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting

  ' ...

  xAxis = New Axis() ' <- dont tie the axis to the chartArea

  ' now, either define the MarginVisible Property to False :
  xAxis.IsMarginVisible = False
  ' either specify the min/max (and eventually the Crossing Property)
  xAxis.Minimum = xValues(0)
  xAxis.Maximum = xValues(xValues.Length - 1)
  xAxis.Crossing = xValues(0) ' optional

  chart1Area.AxisX = xAxis
  chart1Area.AxisY = New Axis() ' everything auto on Y side.

  ' ...
  ```

By the way, my `xValues` is an array of numeric values. Since you put your Years as String, I don't know how it would work. Maybe by using some sort of numeric conversion trick.. :/

So far, I'm not used to `Charting.Chart`, so I hope someone else will help you better. Since I asked you to clarify some things in comments above, this is what I could share so far. If I remember another workaround (somehow forget about Charts long ago) I'll edit this post.

Good luck.

Comment: You spend time to explain in detail everything that I was missing, now my chart looks much better. It didn't cross my mind that I have to define Min and Max values for X axis, to me logical thing would be that the lowest point should go all the way to one side and highest to other (by default). Thank you so much for everything.